# Pyspark load file and specify data type

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, types, pyspark

I would like to load a csv file with PySpark (from AWS S3). I have one column which is specified as integer after loading the data but i would like to have it a string. Is there an option to specify the data type of just one single column?

```
df = (glueContext
          .read
          .option("inferSchema", "false")
          .load('s3://bucket/file.csv',
                           format="csv",
                           sep=",",
                           header=True,
                           inferSchema=True)
         )
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to cast the integer as string after reading the data?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I need to it in as a string because sometimes there are zeros in front and different formats. inferSchema unfortunately does not work.